# How to check if a word is contained in a tuple and if so, remove it

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tuples, nltk

I'm importing a csv file via Pandas, formatted as so:

```
test = [
    ('the beer was good.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
    ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
    ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
    ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
    ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')
]
```

I want to check any words from a stop list are contained within the defined test set, and if so, remove them. However, when trying to do this, I simply get returned the full list without any alterations. Here's my current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',')
tlist = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
tlist = [(x.lower(), y.lower()) for x,y in tlist]

def remove_stopwords(train_list):
        new_list = []
        for word in train_list:
            if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
                new_list.append(word)
        print new_list

remove_stopwords(tlist)
```

I'm trying to use the stopwords provided by the NLTK corpus. Like I said, all that happens when I test this code with a print(new_list) is I get back the tlist set, as it was.

Comment: Why is new_list global? And why do you ignore the return value of remove_stopwords?

Comment: use index function of python to check if an element is present in list or tuple

Comment: @FooBar Sorry, copied some code I was testing to check something. Updated accordingly. And bigbounty What do you mean? Can you explain further?

Comment: Please provide the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of @Vardan is absolutely correct. There must be two loops, one for the **tuple** and another for the **Actual sentence**.
But instead of taking the raw data (in terms of letters), we can convert the string into tokens and check against the **stopwords**.

The below code should work fine:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',')
tlist = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
tlist = [(x.lower(), y.lower()) for x,y in tlist]
def remove_stopwords(train_list):
        new_list = []
        for word in train_list:
            total=''      #take an empty buffer string
            word_tokens=word_tokenize(word[0]) #convert the first string in tuple into tokens
            for txt in word_tokens: 
                    if txt not in stopwords.words('english'): #Check each token against stopword
                        total=total+' '+txt #append to the buffer
            new_list.append((total,word[1])) #append the total buffer along with pos/neg to list
        print new_list

remove_stopwords(tlist)
print tlist
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The word in the for loop is actually a tuple. Because tlist is of the form **[(a1,b1), (a2, b2)]** (list of tuples). And now each tuple is compared with a word in stopwords. If you do this you will see it:

```
def remove_stopwords(train_list):
        new_list = []
        for word in train_list:
            print(word)
            if word not in stopwords:
                new_list.append(word)
        print (new_list)
```

If you would like to remove the words you should at least have two loops one for iterating through the list the other for iterating through the words.
Something like this will work:

```
def remove_stopwords(train_list):
        new_list = []
        for tl in train_list:
            Words = tl[0].split()
            # tl would be  ('the beer was good.', 'pos')
            for word in Words: # words will be the , beer, was, good.
                if word not in stopwords:
                    new_list.append(word)
        print (new_list)
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it works, but a bit too well. The result is that any occurrence of one of the stop words is removed. So for instance, as 'a' is a stop word, any word that contains the letter a now loses it. So "was" becomes "ws". Not only that, but every single letter and space is now in it's own value within the set and the brackets and pos/neg indicators are removed. So, [['t', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'w', 's', ' ', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd'........ is the result.

Comment: I have made changes to the code. I did not split the sentences. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

## try like this:

```
def remove_stopwords(train_list):
        global new_list
        new_list = []
        for line in train_list:
            for word in line:
                if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
                    break
            new_list.append(word)
        return new_list
```

## or like this:

```
def remove_stopwords(train_list):
        global new_list
        new_list = []
        for line, gr in train_list:
            for word in line:
                if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
                    line = line.replace(" %s " % word, ' ')
            new_list.append(word)
        return new_list
```

Comment: Unfortunately my resulting output from trying this was "[]". That's all.

Comment: you must have made mistake somewhere did your csv loaded and processed correctly?  check len(train_list)

Comment: Ah, I missed the print call at the end. Added it in but now I see that instead, no word has actually been removed, apart from the 'pos' or 'neg' in the second part of each line, which I need! I'm trying to get rid of the stop words, so words like "and, a, the, to, it, my" etc.

Comment: I've added another solution